# Youtube Player Android API no fullscreen button anymore

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have a Youtube Player in my Android app and I suddenly got a complaint from a customer that the full screen is not working anymore. So I checked my app and yep! The place where the 'full screen' button (bottom-right) should be, is now a cogwheel, which shows information about the video.

Did anyone else notice this/have this issue? I think I will need to handle the full screen now myself, or is it possible to force this button back?

Comment: This is being tracked at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5532 (reporting bugs in that issue tracker is preferable than using Stack Overflow).

Comment: Thanks for noting me on that! If you would add this as an answer here, I would gladly mark it as an answer!